# SignalR: sending message to userID from database

Tags: android, mysql, asp.net, xamarin, signalr

This is how whole project should work:
1. Mysql database holds all the userIDs
2. There is aspx Webservice (connected to mysql) in the server, which has functions like GetMessage/SendMessage
3. User from client app sends his ID, the receiver ID and a message to Webservice
4. Webservice puts a message into mysql database (with sender ID and receiver ID)
5. SignalR should send notification (e.x. senderID X sent you a message) to the specific user's client app (if he's connected at the time) and the client app then contacts webservice and returns a message from mysql.

Client app is Xamarin android project
Webservice is simple asp.net webservice

**The problem is:**
How to map a connected client with a userID from mysql? Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

[Mapping SignalR Users to Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections) tutorial explains how to do that. While it does not show how to use MySql to persist your data it shows that the storage you choose is not imposed on you - they show two different data repositories used for the purpose of storing user data. You should be able to implement a similar functionality with MySql based on these examples.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a solution!

Comment: One more question. Is IUserIdProvider userId unique? WIll it be the same for the same user everytime?

Comment: Not sure why it matters but since a factory is registred: `GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IUserIdProvider), () => new MyIdProvider());` I believe you will get a new instance each time.